# How to copy and paste to another directory in ubuntu terminal?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am trying to copy and paste a file called s0.scm from my home directory to another directory, but i am getting an error. Here is the command i write to the terminal:

```
cp s0.scm /usr/local/bin
```

I am currently in the home directory and if i write

```
cd /usr/local/bin
```

i can go to that directory without any problems. But when i try to copy a file in my home (current) directory to /usr/local/bin by trying that code, i get the following error:

```
cp: cannot create regular file home/yrazlik/usr/local/bin
```

yrazlik is my username.

What can i do to achieve this? I appreciate any help.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have to be superuser (root) to copy files to /usr/local/bin, try:

```
sudo cp s0.scm /usr/local/bin
```

and give your passwd (yrazlik) when prompt.

Comment: Thanks, but when i tried it, i got the following error: "yrazlik is not in the sudoers file, this incident will be reported"

Comment: If you are not the administrator, placing files in /usr/local/bin is forbidden

Comment: what distribution are you using? you could try to copy it as root.